# MVC jQuery retrieve parameter from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try PartialView just first time.

My plan is as follows:

Up there on the page are going to present 2 date selector fields (from and to), a search button next to them. When the user clicks, the controller builds the result set and it is going to appears in *divResults*.

Here is my page,

```
// /Home/Reports.cshtml

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Report", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "reportform" })) {
<fieldset>
    <legend>Filter</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Date Interval lower bound")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="date_from" type="date" class="datefield" />
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Date Interval upper bound")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input name="date_to" type="date" class="datefield" />
    </div>
    <button id="btnsearch">Search</button>
</fieldset>
}
<div id="divResults">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#btnsearch').on("Click", function (e) {
        var date_from = $("#date_from").val();
        var date_to = $("#date_to").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Report',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { datefrom: date_from, dateto: date_to }
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#divResults").html(partialViewResult);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is my HomeController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Report() {
  return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(string datefrom, string dateto) {
  return null;
}
```

Even though *date_from* and *date_to* contains the desired values, the second (HttpPost) method doesn't catch them.

It looks like all right but it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just remove contentType and try.

Comment: First you need to remove the content type. Secondly, write 'Click' in lower case while binding event to button. i.e. $('#btnsearch').on("click", function(){/* your content */})